# Activiti custom variable type issue

Tags: java, activiti

In Activiti all complex objects are serialized and stored in database using Java serialization. I wish to override this behavior for my custom types and store the objects as JSON. This shall help me to have more control over the persisted object.

I have created my custom VariableType to do this. Below is the snippet

```java
public class CustomVariableType extends ByteArrayType{
// overrided all the needed method.
}
```

These types are configured in activiti configuration impl as below:

```java
public class WorklistConfigurationService {

    private ProcessEngineConfigurationImpl processEngineConfigurationImpl;
    private List<CustomVariableType> customVarsTypes;
    public void init(){
        logger.debug("inside init");
        for(VOVariableType varType : voVars){
            logger.debug("adding type {}", varType.getTypeName());
            processEngineConfigurationImpl.getVariableTypes().addType(varType, 0);
        }
    }
   // getter and setters...
}
```

Below is how I am injecting values to above in Spring

```xml
<bean id="processEngineConfiguration" class="org.activiti.spring.SpringProcessEngineConfiguration">
        <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource" />
    </bean>
    <bean id="worklistConfigurationService"
        class="...WorklistConfigurationService" init-method="init">
        <property name="customVarTypes">
            <list>
                <bean id="var1" class="...CustomVariableType">
                    <constructor-arg type="java.lang.String" value="custom" />
                    <constructor-arg type="java.lang.Class"
                        value="..CustomType" />
                </bean>
            </list>
        </property>
        <property name="processEngineConfigurationImpl" ref="processEngineConfiguration" />
    </bean>
```

But the new serialization mechanism is never used by activiti engine. Instead it is always default serialization which is used. Can someone help in getting this resolved.

Comment: Did you also override the `isAbleToStore` method in `CustomVariableType`?  And what is a voVar?

Comment: @matts I was just trying to hide my business class names. renamed voVars to custom types. Yes I have overrided isAbleToStore method.

Comment: I do not know how but the same piece of code worked. My bad, can someone close this issue. BTW I am planning to share this on GIST so that this can be referred. This is one of the least documented but very useful feature. Shall update here once m done with GIST. Moderator please lemme know if sharing code links is not allowed.

Answer (score 1):

I finally got the root cause of issue. In `DeserializedObject` class below is the code

```java
public class DeserializedObject {

  Object deserializedObject;
  byte[] originalBytes;
  VariableInstanceEntity variableInstanceEntity;

  public DeserializedObject(Object deserializedObject, byte[] serializedBytes, VariableInstanceEntity variableInstanceEntity) {
    this.deserializedObject = deserializedObject;
    this.originalBytes = serializedBytes;
    this.variableInstanceEntity = variableInstanceEntity;
  }

  public void flush() {
    // this first check verifies if the variable value was not overwritten with another object
    if (deserializedObject==variableInstanceEntity.getCachedValue() && !variableInstanceEntity.isDeleted()) {
      byte[] bytes = VOVariableType.serialize(deserializedObject, variableInstanceEntity);
      if (!Arrays.equals(originalBytes, bytes)) {
        variableInstanceEntity.setBytes(bytes);
      }
    }
  }
}
```

This line is the cause of issue:

```java
byte[] bytes = SerializableType.serialize(deserializedObject, variableInstanceEntity);
```

Code always uses `SerializableType` to serialize the object. And serialization defaults to default serialization. And there by an issue...

I do not know now how to move further.

Comment: I am in discussion on this @ activiti forum as well. Please follow the conversation here http://forums.activiti.org/content/custom-serialization-complex-process-variable